# Not able to generate correct payload hash to connect to Amazon SQS from JMeter

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jmeter, performance-testing, amazon-sqs

I am trying to push messages to Amazon SQS from Jmeter.

But i am not able to generate the proper payload hash.

I am sending a message to the queue using a POST request.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://host_url/queue_name?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=Trial&MessageGroupId=1&Expires=2021-01-31T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2012-11-05'
```

The request is not having a body. So I was expecting the payload hash to be generated on an empty String, which would be

```
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

But it is expecting a different one.

Why is it so?

On what argument do I have to generate the payload hash?

Here is my code to generate the hash.

```
 public static String getHexDigest(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException  {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            byte[] digest = md.digest();
            String hex = String.format("%064x", new BigInteger(1, digest));
            return hex;
           
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the algorithm your application is using, looking at [Authenticating requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-api-request-authentication.html) chapter it could be:

1. [Derive a Signature Version 4 Signing Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-java)
2. Base64-encode the request signature
3. Set timestamp for the request expiration

The above links contain Java code examples.

However according to the aforementioned guide:

> Amazon SQS supports Signature Version 4, which provides improved SHA256-based security and performance over previous versions. When you create new applications that use Amazon SQS, use Signature Version 4.

If this is the case you can refer to [How to Handle Dynamic AWS SigV4 in JMeter for API Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-dynamic-aws-sigv4-in-jmeter-for-api-testing) article

Comment: Let me  be more specific.
I am trying to derive the cannonical request for Signing. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html).
CanonicalRequest =
  HTTPRequestMethod + '\n' +
  CanonicalURI + '\n' +
  CanonicalQueryString + '\n' +
  CanonicalHeaders + '\n' +
  SignedHeaders + '\n' +
  HexEncode(Hash(RequestPayload))

Comment: The hash i generate is always wrong.I am  specifically looking for inputs on creating on Hash